# Is the forex market large enough for copytrading?

Tags: investing, foreign-exchange, markets

Let's say I have a strategy where I take 2 trades at the same time every day. With 1:1 risk to reward ratio, and the strategy works 60% of the time.

Let's say I share my picks every day with 10, 20, 100, 500 people and they all take the same trades around the same time. It's all fun and good when we're trading microlots, but what if we're all trading 100 lots? Or 1,000? Could that actually change the market? Obviously, this will depend on the pair, but let's say I'm trading the EUR/USD and USD/JPY.

Am I completely foolish in even asking?

Comment: I can't vouch for the validity of the comment, but someone I found claimed to trade 50,000 lots, which apparently doesn't move the EUR/USD market during normal market hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have a strategy where I take 2 trades at the same time every >day. With 1:1 risk to reward ratio, and the strategy works 60% of the time.

Out of 100 trades, it is just almost impossible to success 60 trades, it is gonna be much less than 60, it is a fact. And having a 1:1 RRW, even though you achieve 50 trades out of 100, it will be a break even if you are lucky enough, so as it is mentioned before you will loose money. The suggestion is to increase RRW ratio, because anyway having over 50% successful trades is a work of a hero. I do not say it is not possible, but obviously you are on the wrong way by setting such RRW and success rate.

> Let's say I share my picks every day with 10, 20, 100, 500 people and they all take the same trades around the same time. It's all fun and good when we're trading microlots,but what if we're all trading 100 lots? Or 1,000? Could that actually change the market? Obviously, this will depend on the pair, but let's say I'm trading the EUR/USD and USD/JPY.

No single person or persons in the world are able to affect the trade direction, so it is not a problem.

> Am I completely foolish in even asking?

No, you are not.

Answer (score 0):

The FX market is the most liquid market, especially the EUR/USD, so no trades you and some 100 or so followers do will move that market.

A bigger concern is your 1:1 reward to risk with only 60% anticipated success rate, you will definitely loose money with this system. A small change in your success rate with a number of consecutive losses and you will be making losses. You need a much larger reward to risk ratio to be successful.

Comment: 1:1 on 60% win rate is excellent on a large number of trades. Most money is made taking constant, controlled losses.

Comment: Are you kidding? In standard Roulette, if you bet on black, it's even money but the house wins about 53% of the time. Are you saying casinos will definitely lose money with standard Roulette and people betting on black? That's insane -- they reliably make money.

Comment: @misantroop - you don't know much about trading go you. As Sunuba mentions, and as I was referring to, it is very hard to get over 50% success rate, and if you do you are doing really well. However, you make money in trading by having a average Reward to Risk ratio of 2, 3 or more to 1. Some of the best traders I know have a success rate of around 40% but have Reward to Risk ratios of above 3:1. You make your money by letting your winners run and keeping your losses small. I would not bother taking a trade where I would risk $500 in order to make $500.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - no one is talking about roulette, I think you are at the wrong table.

Comment: Has anyone here mentioned getting over 50% is easy? No. And keep the personal attacks to yourself.

Comment: 1:1 on 60% win rate is excellent and you can do great with stats like that. The assumption that the average profit has to exceed average loss by multiples is wrong. Your personal preferences are irrelevant, we are judged on the results. As David mentions, gambling operations or just about any business follows the same principles. Operating in the 30-40% success rate category has the risk of a long strings of losses, the rate implies they have more losing streaks than those operating at 60%.

Comment: @misantroop - you do realise that the OP is not getting 60% success rate, he is suggesting if he had a strategy which did. The problem with that is that if he thinks he can get 60% winners then he is probably fooling himself. Secondly, the problem with aiming for 1:1 RTR is that you get one trade that gaps away from you - you wipe out all your small wins. And even if you were able to achieve a 60% win ratio you would still get a long string of losses. But the crucial thing you are not comprehending is that casinos control the odds, you do not control the odds in trading.

Comment: @Victor If you get a 60% success rate and your average win and average loss are equal, it's precisely equal to the roulette, just *way* better than the casinos get. And they make money reliably. If you think it's different, explain a *relevant* difference. You cannot do it. (Of course, no forex trader reliably wins 60% of the time and has an average gain equal to his average loss. That would be utterly amazing. You'd be a billionaire in a few years.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I just explained it above - a casino controls the odds it gets, a trader does not control their odds - the market controls the odds. The two things are completely different. If you are aiming to trade and are going to risk $100 to try to make $100 you will loose in the long run, because you will be very lucky to get more than 50% wins (the best aim for 40% to 45% winners), and you will make a large loss which will wipe out all your small win. If you think trading is like gambling then don't try trading, just go to your casino and have a good time as you loose your money.

Comment: Victor, the whole discussion is based on the theoretical 60% win rate 1:1 ratio, so what are you actually talking about? You only introduce your subjectivity into the topic. My long-term results are around 60% with 1:1 for the record, many of the things I trade are liquidity constrained and that's why you won't ever see me featured in Forbes.

Comment: If that was the case then according to David you should be a billionaire in a few years. LOL !!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the case. You can go 60%/1:1 for a very long time without realizing that all along you've been taking a very small chance of a very large loss. Eventually, you will suffer that very large loss. So you can make a reliable, say, $150/month for a year and then one month you lose $2,000. (But if it really was the case, which it almost certainly isn't, he'd be a billionaire in a few years. Really.)

Comment: Victor, I specifically said "liquidity constrained", do you know what that means?

Comment: Yes, you are making excuses. Firstly I don't know why anyone in their right mind would trady something with liquidity constraints. One of the most important things to do in trading is to have a system that is not too rigid and bound by too many constraints that you hardly ever get any signals to trade. Secondly, if you are telling me you don't get enough trades to make consitant money with your 60% and 1:1 system, then you haven't really had enough trades to give you a good measure of your success rate and your RTR. How many trades have you actually had?